# How to getFragments() with Support Library 25.0.0 and up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

The `getFragments` method has been annotated with  `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)` in the latest versions of the support library, meaning that it is not for external use. There is no record of this change in the [version history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#rev25-0-0) but with earlier versions I could  use this method in retained fragments to get a reference to the UI fragment - and to re-attach to the new UI fragment after a configuration change (as seen [here](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/RotationPersist2WorkerFragment.java)). How can I achieve the same with the new support library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to get the fragments by id or tag being that they were attached to the Activity using an id or tag.

`fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag");
fragmentManager.findFragmentById(id);`